# how to set 2 buttons in 2 tables 1 under the other on mobile , html django templating

Tags: css, html-table, html-email, display

My html is going to be sent as an email via a email service. so it will be read/displayed in gmail, yahoo mail, outlook and etc.
That is why I cannot use inline-flex.
(I tried making classes using max-width but they are ignored).
This is what I have in my file, which I include where it is needed:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" style="width: 180px;min-width: 50%;max-width: 100%">
            <div align="center" style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 6px; color: #ffffff;line-height:15px;background-color: #24b646;width: 180px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;margin: 30px 0 30px 60px; height: 45px;" class="mobileWidth100 mobilePadding0">
                <a width="auto" href="{{extra.manage_team}}" target="_blank" alias="" style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:1px;height: 45px;line-height: 15px;vertical-align: middle;display:table-cell;">{% trans 'Manage Team'%}</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td align="left" style="width: 180px;min-width: 50%;max-width: 100%">
            <div align="center" style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 6px; color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #24b646; line-height:15px;background-color: #ffffff;width: 180px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;height: 45px;">
                <a width="auto" href="{{extra.billing_overview}}" target="_blank" alias="" style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #24b646; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:1px;height: 45px;line-height: 15px;vertical-align: middle;display:table-cell;">{% trans 'Billing Overview'%}</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is how it looks on desktop which partially fine (I will need to bring the first button more to the left):

[image]

And this is how it looks on mobile, as you can see, clearly broken:

[image]

All I want is to have 1 objects one near the other, and then on mobile, the second to go down, and both to have the same width as their parents

Comment: You can do this using html frameworks (like Bootstrap) classes, or using media queries in your css file.
@media (max-width:768px){...}

Comment: Like I said, this is for django templating, which means this html is being sent as an email. Email clients strip down classes. I tried using classes but they just are ignored and nothing happens. Maybe it was unclear in my title, so I edited also my response

Comment: I don't think you can do that with an email as you would need to use a media query and they are not widely supported in email clients (although I cannot find a recent list of clients that support them)

Comment: this has nothing to do with django templates - you'd get exactly the same result however the HTML is generated (including with purely static HTML).

Comment: @ArthurM - This is for a HTML Email, not a website. 
This cannot utilise bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what made it work after all those tries:

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" style="overflow-x:auto;margin: 30px 60px 0px 60px; width: calc(100% - 120px);">
<tr>
    <td>
      <table style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <tr>
          <td
            align="left"
            style="width: 180px;min-width: 50%;max-width: 100%"
          >
            <div
              align="center"
              style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 6px; color: #ffffff;line-height:15px;background-color: #24b646;width: 180px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;height: 45px;"
            >
              <a
                width="auto"
                href="{{ extra.manage_team }}"
                target="_blank"
                alias=""
                style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:1px;height: 45px;line-height: 15px;vertical-align: middle;display:table-cell;"
                >{% trans 'Manage Team'%}</a
              >
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <tr>
          <td
            align="left"
            style="width: 180px;min-width: 50%;max-width: 100%"
          >
            <div
              align="center"
              style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 6px; color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #24b646; line-height:15px;background-color: #ffffff;width: 180px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;height: 45px;"
            >
              <a
                width="auto"
                href="{{ extra.billing_overview }}"
                target="_blank"
                alias=""
                style="font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #24b646; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:1px;height: 45px;line-height: 15px;vertical-align: middle;display:table-cell;"
                >{% trans 'Billing Overview'%}</a
              >
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up, you should have a backup font to Lato, which will not work with Outlook, Gmail or a few other email clients that do not support web fonts.

If your text for your button goes for two lines, you're going to need to reconfigure this to look good in Outlook. A button should never need two lines. This is a good template to get you going forward.

First off, you need a media query:

```
<style>
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .stack-in-mobile {
      display: block !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Next, you're going to need a table container for your email.

This sample is a very simple two button table, reflecting what you wanted. I adjusted the padding to make them roughly the same size.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="stack-in-mobile">
      <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin: auto;">
        <tr>
          <td style="border-radius: 6px; background: #24b646;">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" style="background: #24b646; border: 1px solid #24b646; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 15px; text-decoration: none; padding: 13px 22px; color: #ffffff; display: block; border-radius: 6px; letter-spacing: 1px;">Manage Team</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="stack-in-mobile">
      <table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="margin: auto;">
        <tr>
          <td style="border-radius: 6px; background: #ffffff;">
            <a href="#" target="_blank" style="background: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #24b646; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 15px; text-decoration: none; padding: 13px 12px; color: #24b646; display: block; border-radius: 6px; letter-spacing: 1px;">Billing Overview</a> 
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/h24e3fzx/

I'll leave you to style the rest.

Good luck.

Comment: This will work and I know OP hasnt said anything about which devices he/she is supporting but if `td` has to be `th` for it to work on Android 4 and below.

Comment: @Syfer The button works in Android 4.4, but it will not stack. Stacking is the same issue with Andoid 6 and currently, IOS Outlook for 11. I would be lying if I said I tested this with Donut, Froyo or Honeycomb. I'm not sure I could come up with a more ridiculous sounding statement than stating I tested something in Froyo.

Comment: I don't need to test on a specific device. Can't use chrome, firefox or others. I need to be able to see this in mail clients. Now @media works on desktop. But on the phone versions, Gmail and Ymail ignore classes from the media so I cannot set different code for mobile or desktop version :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stupid question But did you use an external css source? And a lot of CSS cant be used in email template. this is from a template i made and should work on your use case.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 " />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important; font-family: 'ubuntu', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
        table { border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0px; mso-table-rspace: 0px;}
        .table-button a:visited { color: #fff; }
        .table-button a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
        .no_m { margin: 0px;}
        @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:649px) {
            .em_main_table { width: 100% !important; }
            .em_wrapper { width: 100% !important; }
            .em_hide { display: none !important; }
            .em_full_img { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }
            .em_center { text-align: center !important; }
           
            .em_h20 { height: 20px !important; }
            .em_ptop { padding-top: 20px !important; }
            .em_pbottom { padding-bottom: 20px !important; }
            .em_pad1 { padding: 20px 10px !important; }
            .header1_pad { padding: 0px 10px 20px 0px !important; }
            .em_hauto { height: auto !important; }
            .dimensions_30012018 { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; }
            .em_data-tablet { display: table-cell !important; }
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 649px) {
            .em_block { display: table-row !important; }
            .top-half { width: 50% !important;}
            .mobile_button { width: 100% !important; display: inline-block !important; padding: 5px 0px !important;}
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            .em_main_table { width: 100% !important; }
            .em_wrapper { width: 100% !important; }
            .em_hide { display: none !important; }
            .em_center { text-align: center !important; }
            .em_hide1 { display: none !important; }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="em_body" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" bgcolor="#f3f8fc">
<table role="presentation" class="em_wrapper" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">
            <table role="presentation" align="center" width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_main_table" style="width:650px; table-layout:fixed;" bgcolor="#f3f8fc">

                <tr>
                <td mc:edit="zorgexpert" valign="top" align="center" style="padding:35px 25px 35px 25px; background-color:#ffffff;" class="em_pad1" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" class="em_black em_m_l" colspan="2" style="font-family:ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:22px;color:#333333;padding:11px 0px 19px;" valign="top">
                                    <table role="presentation"  align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                                <table role="presentation" class="em_wrapper" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="mobile_button">
                                                            <a class="em_link_nu" href="" style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;font-weight:700;display:block;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;" target="_blank">
                                                                <table role="presentation" width="240" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#F2922C" align="left" style="width:240px;background-color:#04A0DA;border-radius:6px;" class="table-button table-button-bl em_wrapper">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" class="em_white" height="41" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" valign="middle">
                                                                             <span class="em_white" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">
                                                                                 Button
                                                                             </span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td height="10" width="10px" class="em_hide" style="height:10px; width:10px; line-height:0px; font-size:0px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                        <td class="mobile_button">
                                                            <a class="em_link" href="" style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;font-weight:700;display:block;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;" target="_blank">
                                                                <table role="presentation" width="240" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#F2922C" align="left" style="width:240px;background-color:#F2922C;border-radius:6px;" class="table-button table-button-or em_wrapper">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td align="center" class="em_white" height="41" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;" valign="middle">
                                                                             <span class="em_white" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">
                                                                                 Button
                                                                             </span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Still one after the other one. All your classes and @media gets ignored by gmail :(
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/KB6Uk08jDAuEaHS/upload.png